# Strange GET request in Apache Log

Tags: apache, ftp

I'm monitoring my website with apache log and i saw some stranges requests, see:

```
51.255.65.74 - - [28/May/2016:11:48:02 -0300] "GET /insert/xahanave.html HTTP/1.1" 404 1035 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; AhrefsBot/5.1; +http://ahrefs.com/robot/)"
207.46.13.128 - - [28/May/2016:11:49:13 -0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 14188 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
66.249.64.87 - - [28/May/2016:11:49:32 -0300] "GET /css/kin8tengoku-1144-may.html HTTP/1.1" 404 1039 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
```

Well, my FTP don't have the folder "/insert/xanahave", neither file 'kin8tengoku' in folder css. Is it possibile make a request to a non existen file/folder ?

Important: Some days ago my site was hacked and a "insert" folder was created without permission in FTP, but now everything was clean and folder "insert" don't exist anymore. My big question is, why requests to this folder continue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the files were picked up by Ahrefs, Bing search engine and Google search engine when they were up and they periodically recheck files to see if there are any changes. This is how Google and the like return up to date information on your site.

You can see it's these companies from the user agent sent (at the end of each line). Now some, more nefarious bots, sometimes pretend to be GoogleBot but a quick Google of these IP addresses show these to be legitimate ones.

As you can see your server correctly responds with a 404 (page not found status) and, providing there are no links to them, then these companies will eventually take the hint and drop them from their index and stop requesting them. Can take a month or two. They don't do this immediately in case the 404 is an error because you accidentally removed the page or similar.

Comment: Thanks, now i understand better this request.